# How to make end portal Minecraft Pocket Edition v0.16.2

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't seem to make an end portal in *Minecraft Pocket Edition* v0.16.2. Could someone help me? I have the end portal frame but I can't get the Eye of Ender.

Answer (score 0):

**Eyes of ender were added to 1.0 and are therefore not available in 0.16.2.**

<s>[Eyes of Ender] [1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Eye_of_Ender) can be made by crafting 1 blaze powder and 1 ender pearl. In creative, eye of ender can be found in the tools section (iron sword icon).</s>

If you can still not find it and you have cheats enabled, you could type `/give @p ender_eye` in chat.

In creative, if you are making an end portal you need to make sure the [green tabs (see picture) are facing inwards] [2](https://www.digminecraft.com/getting_started/how_to_make_end_portal.php) otherwise it would not work.

[image: How to make an end portal]

Comment: it didnt work for ender eye or ende pearl are you sure you have the right version

Comment: Sorry I forgot that eyes of ender were only added in 1.0.

Comment: well there are end portal frames

Comment: @Nathaniel Yes it's very annoying that they partially add things.

Answer (score 0):

Put the end portal frames in a 5x5 area and then cut out the corners. Then, put in all your eyes of ender inside. REMEMBER: When placing in the frames, make sure that they have been placed from the inside of the portal, or the outside. When you put the frames sideways, it won't work.